# Univalent functions have simple poles

Tags: complex-analysis

I am not able to prove that every one-one function can't have a pole of higher order or more than one pole in the domain D. Can someone give its proof?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are injective functions, not univalent functions.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:Consider the analytic $1/f$ and the vanishing derivative.For the second part,at most one pole what is the image of nhds
about poles under $1/f$ ?